# Curve fitting a simple graph

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a code that uses curve_fit function for fitting.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint    
c_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,10]
b_data = [0,6,9,10,13,14,20]
    def myfunc(a,b):
       def func2(c,a):
           return b*c
       c0 = c_data[0]
       something = odeint (func2, c0, a)
       return something [:,0]
p0 = np.array([1,1,1,2.0])
a_fit, acov = curve_fit(myfunc, c_data, b_data, p0=p0)
```

and the problem starts here. because `myfunc` takes exactly 2 arguments, but 4 are given? I need to have `p0` in case it doesn't fit well otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really have a function within a function or is it a copy-paste mistake? What is `z` here? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: yes function in a function. z was a typo sorry for the mistake.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55078451/how-to-use-curvefit-in-python should be of use, try to run the code in my answer there.

Comment: If I use your code and just copy my data  I get this "axis -1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0"

Comment: @NoobProgrammer: You should put a complete working code in your question which includes all the necessary import commands. Currently people will have to search for the imports and figure out how to run your code. This is simply too much work

Comment: Im so sorry, I added it :(

Comment: I see a few problems here: Your first problem is that `myfunc` takes---as you mention---2 arguments but `p0` is an array of 4. What initial guesses are those? Second `func2` has arguments `c` and `a` but uses `b` and `c`. Something odd there! Finally `odeint`'s third argument is supposed to be an array which is not necessarily ensured here.

Comment: I also do not see the necessity to define `func2` inside of `myfunc`

Comment: I was fitting concentration on a speed rate value. so it was basically func2 was to fit k and my func 2 was to fit solve c with a certain k. I hope it makes sense.